# How to use TV-Out now multiple UIScreens is supported in iOS 4?

Tags: iphone, ios4, television

I just did a quick test with UIScreen's +screens method, to see if the TV Out would also be seen as a UIScreen. Unfortunately, +screens returns only one screen (that of the iPhone itself). So how to display stuff on the TV-Out?

Thanks.
M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is possible. Make sure you have another screen connected (i.e. that you have the video cable connected through a universal dock).

Also, if you are interested in mirroring the display, see:
http://www.expertisemobile.com/2010/06/24/presenting-your-apps-on-the-big-screen-screen-mirroring-for-ios/

Comment: Hi There,

Do you know how it can be done on a non-iPhone 4 or iPad? [UIScreen screens] returns only 1 screen on a iPhone 3G or 3Gs when its connected with a video cable.